# How to Log output of Local Multithread HTTP Server python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, http

i have simple http python multi threaded server

```
#http_server_threads.py

from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
import threading


class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type',
                         'text/plain; charset=utf-8')
        self.end_headers()
        message = threading.currentThread().getName()
        self.wfile.write(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.wfile.write(b'\n')


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Handler)
    print('Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop')
    server.serve_forever()
```

if i do curl

```
(base) padmanabanpr@padmanaban ~ % curl localhost:8080                   
Thread-1
(base) padmanabanpr@padmanaban ~ % curl localhost:8080
Thread-2
(base) padmanabanpr@padmanaban ~ % curl localhost:8080
Thread-3
```

while running this python code i get

```
% python3 http_server_threads.py 
Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2021 10:13:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2021 10:13:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2021 10:14:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I need this output to be logged to a file instead of displayed,
the output that needed to be logged : *(ip - - datetime "request type" response code - )*

Comment: So what is the problem by simply redirecting it into a file, i.e. `python3 http_server_threads.py  2> file` ? Also see [log_message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.log_message): *"...This is typically overridden to create custom error logging mechanisms...."*

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for log_message information. The problem with redirecting is that I should get this log for every 5 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could log message by using this code

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
import threading


class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type',
                         'text/plain; charset=utf-8')
        self.end_headers()
        message = threading.currentThread().getName()
        self.wfile.write(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.wfile.write(b'\n')
        with open('server.log','a') as log_file:
            log_file.write(str(self.client_address)+' '+self.log_date_time_string()+' '+self.request_version+'\n')

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Handler)
    print('Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop')
    server.serve_forever()
```

the output of the message would be like :

```
python https_server_threads.py
Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2021 12:12:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2021 12:12:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2021 12:12:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2021 12:12:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2021 12:12:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

if you check the file *server.log* you get

```
('127.0.0.1', 60328) 15/Aug/2021 12:12:33 HTTP/1.1
('127.0.0.1', 60330) 15/Aug/2021 12:12:33 HTTP/1.1
('127.0.0.1', 60332) 15/Aug/2021 12:12:34 HTTP/1.1
('127.0.0.1', 60334) 15/Aug/2021 12:12:34 HTTP/1.1
('127.0.0.1', 60336) 15/Aug/2021 12:12:36 HTTP/1.1
```